# Appstore version API is giving different version

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, app-store, version

I am using this version lookup API for checking the updated version:

https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?bundleId=xxx.yyyyy.zzz

The result is different when i call API from mobile app, Postman and AppStore

from code, it is showing old version in xcode debug 3.0.0: [image: Xcode debug]

In Postman it is showing correct version 4.0.0: [image]

In AppStore, it is also showing correct version 4.0.0: [image]

Why it is not showing correct version when i am calling API from xcode and mobile app?
I am using alamofire:

```
let bundleId = Bundle.main.infoDictionary!["CFBundleIdentifier"] as! String
AF.request("https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?bundleId=\(bundleId)").responseJSON { [weak self] response in
    print(response.result)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a caching problem. Try to execute request ignoring cache data

**Update: 14.10.2020**

```
let url = "itunes.apple.com/lookup?bundleId=(bundleId)" 
var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!) 
urlRequest.cachePolicy = .reloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked:
let url = "https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?bundleId=\(bundleId)"
var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)
urlRequest.cachePolicy = .reloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData

Comment: Cool, welcome. I've also update me comment to make it more clear for future visitors.

Answer (score 2):

I am facing the same issue and I tried `urlRequest.cachePolicy` but not working for me.

Below thing is works for me please check URL carefully-

This is my URL-

```
"http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?bundleId=(bundleId)"
```

I Changed with this-

```
"https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?bundleId=(bundleId)"
```

IF you can see in the first URL I used `http` and in the second URL, I use `https`.
Please add HTTPS and then check it works.
Cheers!

Comment: Thanks man. Changing to Https definetely worked for me.